# Evaluate a Special Expression in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, string-parsing

I have string which have a special substrings in a special format:

> $( *variableName* )

And this pattern can repeat nested many times:

$( *variableName* $( *anotherVariableName* ) )

Such as: [ A test string ]

> Here is a test string contain $(variableA) and
>   $(variableB$(variableC))

For this test string  Let assume that

> $(variableA) = A, $(variableB) = B, $(variableC) = C, $(variableBC) = Y

What I want is replace those special patters -> $(variableName) with actual values such as
the resulting string should be:

> Here is a test string contain A and Y

Any suggestion for generic and elegant solution?

Comment: So for your sintax $(variableB$(variableC)) is evaluated as $(variableBC) ?

Comment: You typically do this with a custom parser, which won't be particularly generic nor elegant.

Comment: @MauricioGracia: Yes, you can do it with multiple calls to a `Replace` method. Or you can write a simple parser. The parser will typically be faster, and it's not terribly difficult to build. But your mileage may vary.

Comment: @MauricioGracia The fact that the language is very simple does not mean that it cannot benefit from a parser. What it usually means is that the parser is going to be very simple as well ;-)

Comment: @JimMischel Although you're definitely right about the parsers not being generic, their elegance is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @MauricioGracia Neither the number of control statements nor the use of a particular data structure makes a parser what it is. If something takes a structured text and "understands" its structure, it is a parser. The power of this particular "switch with three cases" comes from a single line in the middle: `var name = Replace(input, ref pos, vars, true);` This is what makes this piece of code a recursive descent parser.

Comment: $(variableB$(variableC))  is evaluated as  $(variableBC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a straightforward solution performing a [*recursive descent parsing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser):

```
public static string Replace(
    string input
,   ref int pos
,   IDictionary<string,string> vars
,   bool stopOnClose = false
) {
    var res = new StringBuilder();
    while (pos != input.Length) {
        switch (input[pos]) {
            case '\\':
                pos++;
                if (pos != input.Length) {
                    res.Append(input[pos++]);
                }
                break;
            case ')':
                if (stopOnClose) {
                    return res.ToString();
                }
                res.Append(')');
                pos++;
                break;
            case '$':
                pos++;
                if (pos != input.Length && input[pos] == '(') {
                    pos++;
                    var name = Replace(input, ref pos, vars, true);
                    string replacement;
                    if (vars.TryGetValue(name, out replacement)) {
                        res.Append(replacement);
                    } else {
                        res.Append("<UNKNOWN:");
                        res.Append(name);
                        res.Append(">");
                    }
                    pos++;
                } else {
                    res.Append('$');
                }
                break;
            default:
                res.Append(input[pos++]);
                break;
        }
    }
    return res.ToString();
}
public static void Main() {
    const string input = "Here is a test string contain $(variableA) and $(variableB$(variableC))";
    var vars = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"variableA", "A"}, {"variableB", "B"}, {"variableC", "C"}, {"variableBC", "Y"}
    };
    int pos = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(Replace(input, ref pos, vars));
}
```

This solution reuses the implementation of `Replace` to built the name of the variable that you would like to replace by calling itself with the `stopOnClose` flag set to `true`. Top-level invocation does not stop on reaching the `')'` symbol, letting you use it unescaped.

[Here is a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/Dysz3n)

Comment: that ideone website looks nice, too bade your example does not really allow any input to test it

Comment: @MauricioGracia Click `[clone]`, edit the string inside the `Main` method, then click `[Submit]`.

Comment: You're right: elegance is in the eye of the beholder. I don't find this "elegant," although I do find it an excellent solution to the problem. Which is why I upvoted it.